# Is view offline option available in Android Youtube API

Tags: android, youtube-api, offline-mode

Developing my first android app using Youtube APIs and looking to add all the features that youtube provides on its actual APP or WEB.

There is the new feature of Offline option available , is this option available on the Youtube Android API's as well ?

Guru's please guide and shed some light on this topic, I am very new to Android development so need some help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Offline access is not a feature at the moment. Google doesn't provide all of the featured in their APIs...

Comment: Is there any update on this? I don't find the APIs still have this capability.