# Can I download my own channel's youTube videos in my Android app

Tags: android, download, youtube, offline, youtube-data-api

I want to download video from youTube in my android app for offline viewing. All of these videos will be owned by me and there is no copyright issue.

Can I download these videos in my app?

EDIT: I want to have sync functionality in app. So, that it can download videos when app connects to wiFi and users are see those videos offline. I know there are few apps like TuberMate which downloads youTube videos, but these kinds of apps don't get approved on Google Play. We are also not planning to release on app store and will install on vendor's tablets directly.

Comment: No, you can't. Refer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32415122/is-view-offline-option-available-in-andriod-youtube-api =(

Comment: Then how do apps like TuberMate works?
I know Google doesn't approve these kind apps in Google Play Store. But we are also not planning to release app in PlayStore.
http://tubemate.net/